# Record audio in background in Windows Phone 8 / 8.1 - not possible?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm looking for a way to record an audio from the phone's mic in the background. Basically I want to run my application in the background so that at specified time (e.g. from 20:00 to 21:00) it records the audio from the mic (NOT during the call), without displaying any UI, and saves it to the disk as audio file (any format).

I've seen comments that it can't be done, but I haven't seen the proof or definite answer. I just found this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx that mentions running code in the background, but I'm not sure it is what I need. I have no experience in Windows Phone development whatsoever, but I have a solid .NET background so I can research my way into developing such simple app, only if it is technically possible.

But before I try exploring SDK, I'd like to know whether it is possible at all. And if it is, I'd appreciate any hints to how can this be done.

Comment: Sounds like a massive invasion of privacy to me, and probably is not possible.

Comment: Coding similar app for any Desktop platform is trivial. Isn't that an "invasion of privacy" then? I'm not planning to submit the app to the store, it's just for my own use (on my personal phone). I'd like to be able to execute any code on my own device.